# Using Fubini/Tonelli to Reformulate the Integral of Cumulative Distribution Functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mu)$ be a probability space, and let $F$ be the cumulative distribution function of the probability measure $\mu$ (that is, $F(x)=\mu((-\infty,x])$ and $\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$ for all $-\infty<a \leq b<\infty$).

Using the Fubini/Tonelli Theorem for nonnegative functions, it may be shown that

$\displaystyle2\int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x)\mu(dx)=1+\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mu(\{x\})\mu(dx)=1+\sum_\limits{x \in \mathbb{R}}\mu(\{x\})^2$, where $\sum_\limits{x \in \mathbb{R}}$ is interpreted as integration with respect to the counting measure.

I'm very confused as to how Fubini/Tonelli comes into play in this scenario; is there a way to manipulate the left hand side into iterated integrals? I should also note that we also have $\mu(\{a\})=F(a)-\lim_\limits{x\rightarrow a^-}F(x)$ and that $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow \infty}F(x)=\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$, though I don't think introducing limits into the work would help at all. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $F(x)=\mu(-\infty,x]=\int_{\Bbb R} \chi_{(-\infty,x]}(y)\text{d}\mu(y)$, where the integrand is measurable and positive, so applying Tonelli's Thm. gives:
$$\begin{align} \int_{\Bbb R} F(x)\text{d}\mu(x) &= \iint\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(y)\text{d}\mu(y)\text{d}\mu(x)= \iint\chi_{(-\infty,x]}(y)\text{d}\mu(x)\text{d}\mu(y) \\ &=\iint\chi_{[y,\infty)}(x)\text{d}\mu(x)\text{d}\mu(y)=\int\mu[y,\infty)\text{d}\mu(y)=\int1-\mu(-\infty,y)\text{d}\mu(y) \\ &= 1-\int\mu(-\infty,x)\text{d}\mu(x) \end{align}$$
Now add $\int_{\Bbb R} F(x)\text{d}\mu(x)$ to both sides to get
$$\begin{align} 2\int_{\Bbb R} F(x)\text{d}\mu(x) &= 1+\int_{\Bbb R}\mu(-\infty,x]-\mu(-\infty,x)\text{d}\mu(x)=1+\int_{\Bbb R}\mu(\{x\})\text{d}\mu(x) \end{align}$$
The claim about the counting measure is just by definition.

Comment: Thank you very much. One quick question: how do we justify the 3rd equality? A change of variables happened is what I'm guessing.

Comment: @Buttfor the integrand is $1$ iff $y\le x$, since we are integrating over $x$, this means the integrand is equal to $\chi_{[y,\infty)}(x)$.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you!